# Get error message when initialize vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

```
void FakeMas::initLSRKeys() {
    const char* lsrKeysInit[]= {
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.categories.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.eventresolution.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.image.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.ondemands.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.programmes.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.recommend.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.schedule.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.scheduleevents.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.search.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.serviceresolve.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.applicationresolve.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.suggestions.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.summaries.baseurl",
        "platform.enhancedmetadata.bootstrap.baseurl"
    };
    endpointLSRKey(lsrKeysInit, lsrKeysInit+14);
}
```

Then get

```
error: no match for call to '(std::__debug::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)
(const char* [14], const char**)'
```

anyone get any idea about this?
THanks

Comment: What is `endpointLSRKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the form `variable(arguments...)` in an initializer (i.e. in a declaration).  When assigning to a variable that already exists, use an assignment or in this case use `assign`:

```
endpointLSRKey.assign(lsrKeysInit, lsrKeysInit+14);
```

Comment: You should rather use `sizeof(lsrKeysInit) / sizeof(*lsrKeysInit)` instead of hardcoding `14`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not an *initialization*: use [`vector::assign()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) instead:

```
endPointLSRKey.assign(lsrKeysInit, lsrKeysInit+14);
```

Calculate the number of elements in `lsrKeysInit` instead of hard-coding the `14` (which would require updating if elements were removed or added from `lsrKeysInit`):

```
endPointLSRKey
    .assign(lsrKeysInit, 
            lsrKeysInit + (sizeof(lsrKeysInit)/sizeof(lsrKeysInit[0])));
```

If C++11 support, you can use [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end):

```
endPointLSRKey.assign(std::begin(lsrKeysInit), std::end(lsrKeysInit));
```